# Plugin to set out of stock product image doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I'm creating a plugin to set a different image for each out of stock product everything is displayed in the dashboard only if you set an image it doesn't work can someone help me solve the problem in the code, I would be very grateful

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Out of Stock Image Changer for WooCommerce
 * Plugin URI: 
 * Description: Automatically changes the product image when it goes out of stock in WooCommerce
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: 
 * Author URI: 
 * License: 
 */


add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_product_image_changer_page' );
function register_product_image_changer_page() {
  add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product', 'Out of stock images', 'Out of stock images', 'manage_options', 'out-of-stock-images', 'render_product_image_changer_page' );
}

function render_product_image_changer_page() {
  global $wpdb;

  if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.', 'woocommerce' ) );
  }

  if ( ! empty( $_POST ) && check_admin_referer( 'update_out_of_stock_images' ) ) {
    $product_ids = isset( $_POST['product_id'] ) ? $_POST['product_id'] : array();
    $out_of_stock_images = isset( $_POST['out_of_stock_image'] ) ? $_POST['out_of_stock_image'] : array();

    foreach ( $product_ids as $index => $product_id ) {
      update_post_meta( $product_id, 'out_of_stock_image', $out_of_stock_images[ $index ] );
    }
  }

  $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish'" );

  ?>
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1><?php _e( 'Out of stock images', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h1>

    <form method="post">
      <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update_out_of_stock_images' ); ?>

      <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th><?php _e( 'Out of stock image URL', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php foreach ( $results as $result ) : ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $result->post_title; ?></td>
              <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $result->ID; ?>">
                <input type="text" name="out_of_stock_image[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $result->ID, 'out_of_stock_image', true ); ?>" class="widefat">
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>

<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Save Changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
</p>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'maybe_change_product_image', 9 );
function maybe_change_product_image() {
global $product;

if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
$out_of_stock_image = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'out_of_stock_image', true );

if ( ! empty( $out_of_stock_image ) ) {
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'show_out_of_stock_image', 20 );
}
}
}

function show_out_of_stock_image() {
global $product;

$out_of_stock_image = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'out_of_stock_image', true );

if ( ! empty( $out_of_stock_image ) ) {
echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $out_of_stock_image ) . '" class="attachment-shop_single size-shop_single wp-post-image" alt="">';
}
}
```

everything works in the dashboard, but if an image is set it is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Out of Stock Image Changer for WooCommerce
 * Plugin URI:
 * Description: Automatically changes the product image when it goes out of stock in WooCommerce
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author:
 * Author URI:
 * License:
 */


add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_product_image_changer_page' );
function register_product_image_changer_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product', 'Out of stock images', 'Out of stock images', 'manage_options', 'out-of-stock-images', 'render_product_image_changer_page' );
}

function render_product_image_changer_page() {
    global $wpdb;
    
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    
    if ( ! empty( $_POST ) && check_admin_referer( 'update_out_of_stock_images' ) ) {
        $product_ids         = isset( $_POST['product_id'] ) ? $_POST['product_id'] : array();
        $out_of_stock_images = isset( $_POST['out_of_stock_image'] ) ? $_POST['out_of_stock_image'] : array();
        
        foreach ( $product_ids as $index => $product_id ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'out_of_stock_image', $out_of_stock_images[ $index ] );
        }
    }
    
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish'" );
    
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1><?php _e( 'Out of stock images', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h1>
        
        <form method="post">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update_out_of_stock_images' ); ?>
            
            <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php _e( 'Out of stock image URL', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $results as $result ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $result->post_title; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $result->ID; ?>">
                            <input type="text" name="out_of_stock_image[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $result->ID, 'out_of_stock_image', true ); ?>" class="widefat">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Save Changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'maybe_change_product_image', 9 );
function maybe_change_product_image() {
    global $product;
    
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $out_of_stock_image = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'out_of_stock_image', true );
        
        if ( ! empty( $out_of_stock_image ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'show_out_of_stock_image', 20 );
        }
    }
}

function show_out_of_stock_image() {
    global $product;
    
    $out_of_stock_image = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'out_of_stock_image', true );
    
    if ( ! empty( $out_of_stock_image ) ) {
        echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $out_of_stock_image ) . '" class="attachment-shop_single size-shop_single wp-post-image" alt="">';
    }
}
```

Comment: I modified the hook but nothing works, if I insert the url of the image, the product image doesn't change

Comment: I had updated the codes on my answer please check

Comment: it does not work on the product page or on the shop page

Comment: I use the hello elementor theme for my website, could it be that there is some incompatibility with the theme?

Comment: I tried these code on Twenty Twenty-Two Theme